# Ito process with random, mean zero drift is a Brownian motion?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Suppose that we have a random variable $Z$ and a process $X_t$ such that: $$dX_t=\mu(Z,X_t,t) dt+ dB_t$$ where $\mu(Z,X_t,t)$ is a smooth function that satisfies $E[\mu(Z,X_t,t)|X_t]=0 \ \  \forall t,X_t$ and $B_t$ is a Brownian motion.

Is $X_t$ generally a Brownian motion? I believe so, because it has quadratic variation and is a martingale. However, this seems strange to me as there is "more uncertainty" regarding the terminal value of $X_t$ than if we just had $dX_t=dB_t$. Can anyone provide me some insight here?

(Sorry for not including details on the underlying measure space. Maybe I need to to answer the question, but I'm not as familiar on those details as I would like).

Comment: This is tricky. I believe that the "zero mean" assumption is unrealizable (except some trivial stuff). The problem is that $X_t$ depends on $Z$ in general.

Comment: That's a fair point. I will rephrase the question to say that $X_t$ is independent of $Z$ to make it a little simpler.

Comment: No, it can't be independent! That's precisely the point.

Comment: How is this a martingale? Let $\mu =1$ for example. We get a Brownian motion with a drift that clearly makes $X_t$ not a martingale. If you're considering solutions under different measures as well, then I am not sure. But for the same probability space where $B_t, Z$ are defined, $X_t$ is in general not even a martingale. Note that just because a process has same quadratic variation as Brownian motion it is not automatically a Brownian motion. A sufficient condition is that it is also a local martingale (Levy).

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't considering the condition that you set. Did you by any chance mean $E(\int_0^t \mu(Z,X_s,s) ds \vert F_u) = 0$, $u<t$? Or something like that.

Comment: Thanks zhoraster, I didn't think hard enough about your initial point. One example that isn't particularly trivial is as follows: suppose $dX_t=\lambda * (Z-X_t) dt + dB_t$ where $Z$ has mean zero and $X_0=0$ (i.e., an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process where the mean is unknown at the start). This would be a martingale with quadratic variation and thus it seems to be a Brownian motion.